# Angular 2 : How can I call function from directive to component?

Tags: angular

Angular web application, added 'screen full' package and used in header worked fine. But when I used to particular page form it will show the error. Cant we used particular page?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XbUB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZv6v.png)

Directive

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

declare var require: any;
const screenFull = require('screenfull');

@Directive({
    selector: '[appToggleFullscreen]'
})

export class ToggleFullscreenDirective {
    @HostListener('click') onClick() {debugger
        if (screenFull.isEnabled) {
            screenFull.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

.html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-dark" (click)="click()">
   <app-feather-icons [icon]="'maximize'"></app-feather-icons>
 </a>
```

component

```
import { ToggleFullscreenDirective } from '../../../shared/directives/fullscreen.directive';

export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild(ToggleFullscreenDirective) appToggleFullscreen = null;

  constructor() {}

  click() {
    this.appToggleFullscreen.onClick();
  }
}
```

I got error "core.js:6150 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined"

Comment: Where are you applying the directive in html?

Comment: @amnah directive is only ts file

Comment: When you are suing @ViewChild, the reference you are using MUST exist in html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.appToggleFullscreen` is undefined, because you're not calling it in html.

```
click() {
    this.appToggleFullscreen.onClick();
  }
```

You have to do it like this,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-dark" (click)="click()" appToggleFullscreen>
  <span>component here</span>
</a>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7sew3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: when i used 'appToggleFullscreen'  in the .html no any action

Comment: In the stackblitz? I have only console.log on click, just to show that the click method is working, you can add your own logic here

Comment: this link html file working fine because this is under shared. When i used with out shared folder page is not working.

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly, you are importing this directive in shared.module? If so, you should export it as well, if you want to use it outside the shared module

Comment: add `  exports: [ToggleFullscreenDirective]` in shared.module and then import SharedModule in other modules file

Comment: Perfect, Thank you